# Formatting Date Picker for Posting to MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I am trying to post the values of text boxes which have been populated from date pickers to my database but I keep getting the value 1970-01-01 being posted instead. I have researched this and can't see where I am going wrong, below are the input types.

```
<label for="from">From:</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">To:</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Inside the form I then have:

```
$fromdate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['from']));
$todate    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['to']));

$request = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (fromdate, todate) VALUES ('$fromdate', '$todate')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're inserting is a string.    If you're inserting it into a DATE field, you'll need to convert it to a date.   The syntax for this will vary depending on what database you're using.   MySQL uses STR_TO_DATE for this, while Oracle uses TO_DATE.  I can help you out with structuring your query if I know what type of database you're using.

Edit: here's your code.  You'll need to leverage the MySQL STR_TO_DATE function inside the query itself.

```
 $request = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (fromdate, todate) 
                         VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(\''.$fromdate.'\',\'%Y-%m-%d\'),
                                 STR_TO_DATE(\''.$todate.'\',\'%Y-%m-%d\')") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, it's not really good practice to handle mysql errors with die() when you go to production.   It could give a malicious user information you don't want them to have.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm using MySQL. Is it just a matter of doing $fromdate  = date('Y-m-d', strtodate($_POST['from']));?

Comment: Have tried that but now its not posting to the database at all. I haven't changed these - $fromdate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['from']));
$todate    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['to'])); Should I have?

Comment: I think there was a syntax error in my answer.   You'll need to escape any single quotes you don't want parsed by PHP.   I've edited my answer to reflect this.  Also, it would be handy to see exactly what kind of date strings you're getting from the POST data.   Using STR_TO_DATE in the SQL should eliminate the need to do any date manipulation in the PHP.

Comment: Also tried that with no joy :( Should I be storing the from date and to date in hidden input fields or anything?

Comment: They should work the way they are.   Are you getting any SQL errors when you try to run the query?

Comment: Not receiving any error and have removed the die part of the query but nothing is being input into the db.

Comment: echo your $fromdate and $todate variables and let's see the output.

Comment: I got it, echo'd it and it was returning a blank value. Turned out I had opened the form after the input type was set. Schoolboy error on my part, thanks for your help. Ended up keeping the format the same as I had posted in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

the problem that strtotime() cant guess the format correctly.

thus you can:

EITHER reformat standard output of DatePicker:
[option-altField](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField)
- you can ignore the regular field and send to db the altField

OR reformat in PHP output
instead `strtotime($_POST['from']))` you can use something like this

```
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('date-time-format-from-datepicker',$_POST['from'])->format('Y-m-d')
```

To make correct format of 'date-time-format-from-datepicker' you can use [php date formatting symbols table](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) - it will take some time but it must work

Comment: I have tried reformatting it but it posts nothing to the DB now, any idea why?

Comment: try to dump what you got after date reformatting, before insert to DB. possible its still incorrectly formatted. OR simply dump your query and try to execute in console. maybe you have mysql warning on insert execute. then launch "show warnings" from mysql console and get description.